# Convert first Letter of each word of a sentence to capital in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have the string:

> i am a bad boy.

I want to convert that string into:

> I Am A Bad Boy.

What I have tried only has worked for the first character of a word.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: no did not used text field i used label.

Comment: NSString *capitalisedSentence = [name stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)  withString:[[name  substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString]];

Comment: it is not working it showing exactly one character in total string

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is Solution:

```
NSString *str=@"i am a bad Boy";
    str=[str capitalizedString];
NSLog(str);
```

output will be:

```
I Am A Bad Boy.
```

Comment: Rishi also told the same but i wrote like this [str capitalizedString] so thats why it is not working now you cleared it perfectly..

Answer (score 7):

use-  `capitalizedString` method.

This method returns:

> A string with the first character from each word in the receiver
>   changed to its corresponding uppercase value, and all remaining
>   characters set to their corresponding lowercase values.

You can check `NSString` documentation for more details -
 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: This will work only for first word not for remaining other words in a sentence

Comment: This will work as long as word are seperated properly. As mentioned in docs "A “word” here is any sequence of characters delimited by spaces, tabs, or line terminators ". So as long as word are seperated by any of above it will work perfectly.